# c# bulk add comments with excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, comments, excel-interop

I have a datatable (created in my code) and an existing spreadsheet on disk. I want to dump the data in the datatable to the spreadsheet cells as comments. Doing this inside "nested for loops" and navigating the excel cell-by-cell to add comments in each cell is taking lot of time. I would like to know if there is a better performance operation or another workaround that could do this?

Excel interop offers batch editing for values like so:

```
object[,] data = MY_DATA;
Range[Cells[1,1], Cells[x,x].Value2 = data;
```

Is there an equivalent API for comments?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to open source library then you should try EPPlus (Url: http://epplus.codeplex.com/). You can open any existing excel file with EPPlus and use AddComment method to provide comments to the cells.

```
private static void AddComment(ExcelWorksheet ws, int colIndex, int rowIndex, string comment, string author)
{
    //Adding a comment to a Cell
    var commentCell = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];
    commentCell.AddComment(comment, author);
}
```

Comment: thats actually not the problem. i am able to add comments using the cells.addcomment method of interop . but cell-by-cell adding is inefficient. I want to check if there is something i could bulk update... the way we have efficient ways of reading and writing data to excel, i was hoping, there was a better way to write comments in excel cells too.